# Why does the list inside the loop become empty after filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-2.x

I am trying lambda functions in python 3. I tried the example (to find prime number) given here in this link: 
http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk
This did not work in python 3.

I am trying to assign the same global variable after filtering. unable to make it work.

The variable primes becomes empty array after the first loop. 
Does anyone have any idea ?

```
def test1():
    num = 50
    primes = range(2,num); 
    for i in range(2, 8): 

        print(list(primes)); 
        primes = filter(lambda x: x % i, primes); 
        print(list(primes), i); 

    print("last"); 
    print(list(primes)); 

test1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` [returns an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). Once the iterator is exhausted, as it is by `list` in your code, you cannot reuse it.

The reason this would work in Python 2.x is because `filter` [returned a list](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) in earlier versions.

Below is a minimal example of this behaviour in Python 3.

```
odds = filter(lambda x: x % 2, range(10))

res = list(odds)
print(res)
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

res = list(odds)
print(res)
# []
```

To get round this, assign a list to `primes` instead of an iterator:

```
primes = list(filter(lambda x: x % i, primes))
```